# Cannot Get The Right Answer In A Calculation In C++

Tags: c++

This is my program for a lab. I have to apply two formulas and print answers for both. The first one is in this line:

```
cout<<"Hypoteneus is: " <<sqrt((x*x)+(y*y)) <<endl;
```

This one worked. The problem is in this one:

```
cout<<"Area is: " <<a*x <<((1/2)*x*y);
```

The problem is that it prints its answer as 0. I put the `a*x` for testing, that worked but the expression `(1/2)*x*y` is rendering 0 as answer. I input `x` as 1 and `y` as 2. Please help.

```
int main ()
{
    float x, y, a=122;
    cout<<"Enter x and y.\n";
    cin>>x >>y;
    cout<<"Hypoteneus is: " <<sqrt((x*x)+(y*y)) <<endl;
    fflush(stdin);
    cout<<"Area is: " <<a*x <<((1/2)*x*y);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is straight undefined behaviour. Remove it.

Comment: And unecessary, too.

Comment: Debugging tip:  If you get confused why a line isn't giving you the answer you are expecting, break it up into small pieces and print to find out where it's going wrong:  `cout << (1/2) << ", " << (1/2) * x << ", " << (1/2) * x * y << "\n";`

Comment: @chris yes I thought that it would solve my problem

Comment: @chris sometimes the program leaves a few cin statements, fflush works at that time, is this its right usage?

Comment: fyi: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/hypot

Comment: @user2978059, No, any usage of `fflush(stdin)` is wrong. If you want to pause the program, you really should not pollute the code with it. Run the program from the command line. Put a breakpoint at the end of `main`. Tell your IDE to pause after execution. There are several options that don't change the code. If you absolutely must, use `std::cin.ignore` to ignore remaining input (only if there is any) and `std::cin.get()` as an equivalent of `getch()`.

Answer (score 9):

`((1/2)*x*y)` should be `((1.0/2.0)*x*y)` or `(0.5*x*y)`.

Otherwise, the compiler will understand `int/int` and the result will be `int` so your expected `0.5` will become `0`.

Answer (score 3):

`1/2` specifies integer arithmetic, truncating the result to the nearest integer, which is zero.

Use `0.5f` or `1.0f/2.0f` for a `float` constant with the right value. Or divide by two instead of multiplying by a half.